# How to save \url and special characters into a token list?

Tags: latex3, urls

I'm trying to fix [zepinglee/citeproc-lua#30](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues/30) which can be simplified as follows. The `.bbl` file generated by `citeproc-lua` with citations and bibliography in it and it is read by LaTeX at `\begin{document}` (for non-LuaTeX engines). The content of `thebibliography` in the `.bbl` file is saved into a token list which is then used for output or regression test. However this procedure fails if `thebibliography` contains `\url`s with special characters like percent signs. How can I make it work?

Besides, the citation results are included in `.bbl` from `citeproc-lua` and they are also saved for use in `\cite` commands. In note style bibliography, the citations may contain `\url`s, which is a similar issue.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{url}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
\RenewDocumentEnvironment { thebibliography } { m +b }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__csl_bibliography_tl {#1}
  }
  { }
\NewDocumentCommand { \printbibliography } { }
  {
    \tl_use:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
  Foo 20\% bar \url{foo%20bar}
\end{thebibliography}

\printbibliography
% Expect the same output as:
% Foo 20\% bar \url{foo%20bar}

\end{document}
```

The above code gives an error.

```
Runaway argument?
\begin   Foo 20\% bar \url {foo\end {thebibliography} \par \printbibliography \
ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \environment thebibliography .
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

Comment: well either write `\url{foo\%20bar}` in the input or set the catcode of % to other before reading your argument.